# mongoose conditional required field validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

According to mongoose [built-in validators documentations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators), I can use conditional required field:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    a: {
        type: String,
        required: function () {
            return this.b === 1
        }
    },
    b: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
```

In this schema the property `a` is required only when property `b` equals to `1`.

Trying to create a new document works as expected:

```
Model.create({ b: 1 }); // throws ValidationError (property a is required)
```

and

```
Model.create({ b: 2 }); // creates document
```

My problem is trying to update an existing document and set property `b` to `1` so property `a` should be required.

Running the following code:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(model._id, { b: 1 }, { new: true, runValidators: true});
```

unexpectedly updates the document without throwing an error that property `a` is required.

My guess is that the validation is running only for the updated properties (property `b`) and not the whole document.

I am not sure if this is the expected behavior or a bug...

Am I missing something?
Is there any way to run the validators for the whole document and not only the updated properties without having to manually fetch the document before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with middlewares and validators without any success, I could achieve this requirement by using [`transactions`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) (Available from `MongoDB 4.0` and `Mongoose 5.2.0`)

```
// Create a transaction session
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();

// Fetch the model (pass the session)
const model = await Model.findById(modelId).session(session);

// ... update your model here

// Validate the schema
if (model.b === 1 && !model.a) {
    throw new mongoose.ValidationError('property a is required');
}

// Save the changes
await model.save();
await session.commitTransaction();
```

Note that I don't attach the `session` to the `save` function because it is already attached from fetching the model using `find`:

> If you get a Mongoose document from findOne() or find() using a session, the document will keep a reference to the session and use that session for save().

One problem I found with this approach is that `MongoDB` currently only supports `transactions` on replica sets.
There is an option to run it locally without replica sets for development using `run-rs`

> To run a local replica set for development on macOS, Linux or Windows, use npm to install run-rs globally and run run-rs --version 4.0.0. Run-rs will download MongoDB 4.0.0 for you.

For further information you can check both [Mongoose documentations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) for transactions and [MongoDB documentations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#transactions)

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement the middle ware   normally called "hooks" you can read more on this 
and implement your needs 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: This is not correct, with the hooks I have no access to property `a` if I update property `b` only, so there is still no way to validate the field without fetching the document before.